# Filtered array Else condition renders on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter, state

I'm filtering data (*coming from useFetch hook*) array like so:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const result = [...data].filter(
        item => (!input || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())) &&
        (!select || item.dep === select)
    );
    setFilteredData(result);
    }, [data, input, select]);
```

And outputing in the DOM like so:

```
{filteredData.length > 0 ? (
    filteredData.map(({name}) => (
        <Component name={name} />
    ))
) : (
    <div>
        <h2>NOT FOUND</h2>
    </div>
)}
```

So I'm updating `data` array with results. The issue is, when I refresh the page, I can see "**NOT FOUND**" showing up briefly before the array results show up. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the data appearing `null` at the beginning of the fetch operation. try this:

```
 {!!filteredData.length > 0 ? (
        filteredData.map(({name}) => (
            <Component name={name} />
        ))
    )}
```

or you can use the loading effect in the component.